# Twincat Serial communication function

Tags: plc, twincat

I am trying out the Twincat TF6340 TC3 serial communication function and is following Example 1 from [here](https://infosys.beckhoff.de/content/1033/tf6340_tc3_serial_communication/27021598166861707.html?id=4144182113103185301).
My objective is to connect an RS422 device to the PC via an Ethercat convertor.
As far as I understand, the fast task (refer [here](https://download.beckhoff.com/download/document/automation/twincat3/TF6340_TC3_Serial_Communication_EN.pdf) for the manual - pg 21) is for enabling communication between the serial device and the COM buffer, and the standard task(FB_SerialCom) is for processing data from the buffer.

Hence my program would need both a standard task and a fast task, wouldn't it?

Ps. I am a beginner in Twincat. Also, I use EL6xxx Ethercat convertor.

Comment: You mention that you are trying to pass the RS422 data to the PC, Is that the PLC or the windows environment? 
If passing data to the windows environment I would recommend using TF6360 to expose the RS422 data directly in a virtual serial port.

Comment: @Steve I am passing it to the PLC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need two different tasks running at different speeds, determined by the baud rate of your communications and how often you want to process the data present on the buffer.

If you examine the [example](https://infosys.beckhoff.de/content/1033/tf6340_tc3_serial_communication/Resources/zip/9007199646873611.zip) included in your reference link then you will see that then then there is two different tasks (2ms, 10ms cycle times).
The high-speed task retrieves data directly from the serial port and loads it onto the message buffer, and the low-speed task processes the data.